# Kivy Label Alignment inside a GridLayout, inside an MDCard

Tags: python, kivy, label, alignment

So, I'm trying to align the Label (or MDLabel) inside a grid layout, inside a card widget. (which is inside a ScrollView, set in my .kv file

(Once I have this working, I also want the card and grid layout to expand vertically with 'amount' of the text in the Label and I have literally NO CLUE how to do that... But that is a future problem, unless you guys know how to do this then help would be super appreciated! :D)

I'm quite new to kivy and kivyMD, and everything I've tried so far hasn't worked all that well...

Here's the code I have so far...

```
        grd_ly_ut = GridLayout(cols=2, rows=1)
        grd_ly_ut.adaptive_width = True
        grd_ly_ut.adaptive_height = True
        grd_ly_ut.size_hint = 1, 1

        # label = MDLabel(text=str(message), size_hint=(1, None), halign="left", valign='top', theme_text_color="Custom", text_color=[1, 1, 1, 1])
        label = Label(text=str(message), size_hint=(1, None), halign="left", valign='top')

        # label.height = int(label.font_size)
        label.texture_size = grd_ly_ut.size
        label.text_size = grd_ly_ut.size
        label.center_y = False

        if username == "Bob":
            grd_ly_ut.add_widget(self.add_profile_image(1))
        if username == "Alice":
            grd_ly_ut.add_widget(self.add_profile_image(3))
        if username != "Alice" and username != "Bob":
            grd_ly_ut.add_widget(self.add_profile_image(2))

        grd_ly_ut.add_widget(label)

        card = MDCard(orientation='vertical', radius=[0], size_hint=(1, None), md_bg_color=[0.23, 0.24, 0.25, 1])
        card.add_widget(grd_ly_ut)
        card.height = "100dp"

        self.ids.MainChatStackLayout.add_widget(card)
```

And this is what it looks like.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bvsja.png)

And this is what it looks like if I use an MDLabel instead (just uncommented the MDLabel)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZB8rt.png)

If I haven't explained this very well, or missed out information, please just ask or let me know.

Any AND ALL help is much appreciated as I have been stuck on this issue for 3 days...

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).